# how to convert void* member from struct to int or char*

Tags: c

hi im working on some drill that i need to create a table of array (without putting some data in it)that each of them point to a linked list that should be chars or int according to the parameter i get.

so the data member is void* and according to the parameter i get i need to create table of chars linked list or table of int linked list.
i cant understand how to put it int or char..
here is the code:

```
typedef struct Object {
    void* data;
    void* next;
    
    
}Object;

typedef struct Table {
    Object** arr;
    
}Table;
```

that was the strucut and here is my code:

```
Table* createTable(int size, int dType, int listLength){   // creating the table
    Table* table = malloc(sizeof(*table));
    
    
    
    
    
   
   table->arr=(Object **)malloc(size * sizeof(Object*));
   table->arr[1]->data=1;
   for(int i=0; i<size;i++){
       for(int j=0;j<listLength;j++){
           Object* node1 =malloc(sizeof(*node1));
           Object* node2;
           if(table->arr[i]==NULL){
               
               table->arr[i]=node1;
               node1->next=NULL;

           }
           else if(node1!=NULL){
               node2=table->arr[i];
               for(int z=0;node2->next!=NULL;z++){
                   node2=node2->next;
               }
                node2->next=node1;
           }
       }
   }
```

in my code i just create an array of object and then each of the entries of the array points to a linked list with size of a listlength parameter that i got and the array itself with the size parameter that i got.
the parameter dtype is the type of the linked list(1 char*,0 int)
so as you see the data here is void* and i need to know how according to the parameter how to do that int or char*

thanks a lot for help!!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there appears to be a bit of confusion in allocating for your nested data structures. Let's see if we can get you straightened out. Before beginning, let's make sure I understand your parameters because there are a number of ways you can put them together. I envision a `listLength` number of `Object` where each `Object` has `size` number of `dType` byte elements:

- `size` is the number of columns of `data` you want per-`Object` in `arr`,
- `dType` is the `sizeof` each of the column elements, and
- `listLength` is the number of rows of `Objects` you want to allocate for in your table.

(all of which should be `size_t` instead of `int` given how they will be used and the types they represent)

What seems a bit off here is in addition to not needed the `struct Table` to declare a pointer of type `Object**`, you don't need a pointer of type `Object**` to allocate for `listLength` number of `Object`. You could just allocate for a block of `Object*` objects and then allocated `size` number of `dType` byte elements for each `data` (but for now we will go with it, let me know if you were thinking different)

To begin, you have `Table`, e.g.

```
typedef struct Table {
    Object** arr;
} Table;
```

While you are free to create a `struct` holding a *pointer-to-pointer* to `Object`, it doesn't really make much sense, since you could have simply created a *pointer-to-pointer* to `Object`, but no worries, it complicates the syntax slightly, but we will go with it. Understand a *pointer-to-pointer* to `Object` (e.g. `Object**`) is just a single-pointer that will point to an allocated block of pointers (`listLength` of them)

So after allocating your `struct Table`, you want to allocate a block of memory to hold `listLength` pointers. You can do:

```
Table *createTable (size_t size, size_t dType, size_t listLength)
{
    Table *t = malloc (sizeof *t);          /* allocate 1 struct table */
    if (!t) {                               /* validate EVERY alloaction */
        perror ("malloc-t");
        return NULL;
    }
    
    t->arr = malloc (listLength * sizeof *t->arr);      /* allocate pointers */
    if (!t->arr) {                                      /* validate EVERY allocation */
        perror ("malloc-t->arr");
        free (t);                           /* on failure, free all prior allocations */
        return NULL;
    }
    ...
```

(**note:** above you validate EVERY allocation, and on an allocation failure at any point, you want to `free()` all prior allocations before returning `NULL` or you will create a memory-leak)

After you have allocated a block of memory to hold `listLength` pointers to `Object`, you want to loop over each pointer and allocate a block of memory to hold a `struct Object` and assign the beginning address to each of your pointers in-turn, e.g.

```
     ...
     for (size_t i = 0; i < listLength; i++) {           /* loop over each pointer */
        /* allocate Object assign to pointer */
        t->arr[i] = malloc (sizeof *t->arr[i]);
        if (!t->arr[i]) {                               /* validate EVERY alloaction */
            perror ("malloc-t->arr[i]");
            while (i--)                     /* on failure, free all prior allocations */
                free (t->arr[i]);
            free (t->arr);
            free (t);
            return NULL;
        }
        ...
```

After allocating each `Object` and assigning to each pointer, you can allocate a block of memory for `size` number of `dType` byte objects and assign the beginning address for each such block to your `data` member pointer of each `struct Object`. Further -- you can do so in the same loop. (which is a tell you have an overly unnecessary layers of declarations needed to point to final storage). To allocated an zero all memory for each `data` element, use `calloc()` instead of `malloc()` which will ensure your block if fully initialized and save you a call to `memset()`, e.g.

```
        ...
        /* allocate size elements of dType bytes for each row w/calloc to zero all */
        t->arr[i]->data = calloc (size, dType);
        if (!t->arr[i]->data) {                         /* validate EVERY alloaction */
            
            perror ("calloc-t->arr[i]->data");
            while (i--) {                   /* on failure, free all prior allocations */
                free (t->arr[i]->data);
                free (t->arr[i]);
            }
            free (t->arr);
            free (t);
            return NULL;
        }
        t->arr[i]->next = NULL;             /* initialize all ->next pointers NULL */
        ...
```

At this point, all you need to do is `return t;` and you are done, e.g.

```
    ...
    }
    
    return t;       /* return allocated pointer */
}
```

You can test your allocation scheme by creating an instance and assigning the return of `createTable()` to it, e.g.

```
int main (void) {
    
    char my_dType;
    size_t rows = 20, cols = 10;
    Table *tbl = createTable (cols, sizeof my_dType, rows);
    
    if (!tbl) {
        fputs ("error: createTable() failed.\n", stderr);
        return 1;
    }
    
    puts ("tbl allocation succeeded.");
}
```

**Memory Allocation Check**

In any code you write that dynamically allocates memory, you have 2 *responsibilities* regarding any block of memory allocated: (1) *always preserve a pointer to the starting address* for the block of memory so, (2) it can be *freed* when it is no longer needed.

It is imperative that you use a memory error checking program to ensure you do not attempt to access memory or write beyond/outside the bounds of your allocated block, attempt to read or base a conditional jump on an uninitialized value, and finally, to confirm that you free all the memory you have allocated.

For Linux `valgrind` is the normal choice. There are similar memory checkers for every platform. They are all simple to use, just run your program through it.

While we have not yet called `free()` on each part of the allocated table, we can check for any memory errors during allocation, e.g.

```
$ valgrind ./bin/table_object_create
==25207== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==25207== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==25207== Using Valgrind-3.13.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==25207== Command: ./bin/table_object_create
==25207==
tbl allocation succeeded.
==25207==
==25207== HEAP SUMMARY:
...
==25207==
==25207== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==25207== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

Always ensure there are no memory errors (last two lines)

Now, I have a suspicion I have over-complicated your allocation scheme (which is fine for the purpose of example). The same scheme applies to your allocations no matter how you want to put it together. If I had to deduce how I would use your nested struct, it looks like it would be logical to simulate a table of linked-lists where you would allocate `listLength` number of pointers to `Object`, then `size` number of `Object` to each pointer, and at that point each allocated object could serve as the beginning of each linked-list. (a simulated 2D array, `listLength x size`, of linked-lists) In that case you would just allocate on `dType` sized block for each `data` serving as the one of the fixed `head` node for each list.

That even sounds a bit odd, doable, but odd. That is the freedom you have putting dynamically created object together. The allocations all work the same, you just have to keep track of the arithmetic that describes how the objects are laid out in memory.

If you can't take the example above and put together the exact arrangement of objects you need, edit your question and describe with clarity exactly how you want the pieces put together. I'm happy to help further.

Look things over and let me know if you have questions. The complete compilable example is below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct Object {
    void* data;
    void* next;
} Object;

typedef struct Table {
    Object** arr;
} Table;

Table *createTable (size_t size, size_t dType, size_t listLength)
{
    Table *t = malloc (sizeof *t);          /* allocate 1 struct table */
    if (!t) {                               /* validate EVERY alloaction */
        perror ("malloc-t");
        return NULL;
    }
    
    t->arr = malloc (listLength * sizeof *t->arr);      /* allocate pointers */
    if (!t->arr) {                                      /* validate EVERY allocation */
        perror ("malloc-t->arr");
        free (t);                           /* on failure, free all prior allocations */
        return NULL;
    }
    
    for (size_t i = 0; i < listLength; i++) {           /* loop over each pointer */
        /* allocate Object assign to pointer */
        t->arr[i] = malloc (sizeof *t->arr[i]);
        if (!t->arr[i]) {                               /* validate EVERY alloaction */
            perror ("malloc-t->arr[i]");
            while (i--)                     /* on failure, free all prior allocations */
                free (t->arr[i]);
            free (t->arr);
            free (t);
            return NULL;
        }
        /* allocate size elements of dType bytes for each row w/calloc to zero all */
        t->arr[i]->data = calloc (size, dType);
        if (!t->arr[i]->data) {                         /* validate EVERY alloaction */
            
            perror ("calloc-t->arr[i]->data");
            while (i--) {                   /* on failure, free all prior allocations */
                free (t->arr[i]->data);
                free (t->arr[i]);
            }
            free (t->arr);
            free (t);
            return NULL;
        }
        t->arr[i]->next = NULL;             /* initialize all ->next pointers NULL */
    }
    
    return t;       /* return allocated pointer */
}

int main (void) {
    
    char my_dType;
    size_t rows = 20, cols = 10;
    Table *tbl = createTable (cols, sizeof my_dType, rows);
    
    if (!tbl) {
        fputs ("error: createTable() failed.\n", stderr);
        return 1;
    }
    
    puts ("tbl allocation succeeded.");
}
```